# Adding new list item using REST

Tags: javascript, office-365, rest, client-object-model

I am currently using Office 365 and lots of REST queries to display data. However I am now creating my own forms using Bootstrap and jQuery.

However, how do I use REST to add the data to the list?

Can I have some code example with the columns, so I can try, please?

Answer (score 25):

[This blog](http://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/create-retrieve-update-and-delete-sharepoint-list-item-using-rest-api-and-jquery/) has a code snippet that is useful:

> ```
> // CREATE Operation
> // listName: The name of the list you want to get items from
> // weburl: The url of the web that the list is in. 
> // newItemTitle: New Item title.
> // success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull
> // failure: The function to execute if the call fails
> function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItemTitle, success, failure) {
>     var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
>     var item = {
>         "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
>         "Title": newItemTitle
>     };
>
>     $.ajax({
>         url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
>         type: "POST",
>         contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
>         data: JSON.stringify(item),
>         headers: {
>             "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
>             "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
>         },
>         success: function (data) {
>             success(data);
>         },
>         error: function (data) {
>             failure(data);
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> // Get List Item Type metadata
> function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
>     return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
> }
> ```

Comment: function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
        return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join('_x0020_').slice(1) + "ListItem";
    }

this works for me if the list name has space in it

Comment: How to deal with authentication? I use this code from the same browser where there I have an open session for that same SPO site and I get 403

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend the article [Manipulating list items in SharePoint Hosted Apps using the REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api.aspx), it contains a thorough description with examples how to perform CRUD operations using REST API in SharePoint 2013.

Below is provided a slightly modified version of function for creating list item from the specified article:

```
function createListItem(siteUrl,listName, itemProperties, success, failure) {

    var itemType = getItemTypeForListName(listName);
    itemProperties["__metadata"] = { "type": itemType };

    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}


// Get List Item Type metadata
function getItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

Usage

```
//specify item properties
var itemProperties = {'Title':'Order task','Description': 'New task'};
//create item
createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Tasks',itemProperties,
   function(entity){
      console.log('New task ' + entity.Title + ' has been created');
   },
   function(error){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code for updating Text,Number,Lookup,Content Type,Single Select managed Metadata columns fields using REST API:

```
item = {
"__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.ABCListItem"
},
"Title": "Name",
"Name": "Name field",
"PId": 736,
"short": "short desc",
"long": "long desc",
"category": "High",
"status": "New",
"ContentTypeId":"0x0100624BD12SDDS5E1C4F54CBF434A4C07E90D630015827ECAAC097748868AAB8A57615B52",
"MetadataSingleSelect": {
    "TermGuid": "4cbeecf8-8833-4328-1234-5679b0a42f46",
    "WssId": -1
}
};
$.ajax({
url: fullurl +"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Listnme')/items",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
data: JSON.stringify(item),
headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},
success: function(data) {
    alert('Success');
},
error: function(data) {
   alert(Error);
}
});
```