# Add Item to List on JSLink with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-list, list-item, crud

I have a JSLink on my Webpart Custom List, and I need to add an item before render a view.

```
(function () {
      var overrideCtx = {};

      overrideCtx.Templates = {};
      overrideCtx.Templates.Header = CustomHeader;
      overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = CustomFooter;
      overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;
      overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;
      overrideCtx.OnPreRender = CustomPreRender;

      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

function CustomPreRender(ctx){
   CotacaoAppDataUpdate(ctx);
   return true;
}
```

On `CustomPreRender` I call this function:

```
function CotacaoAppInsert(ctx, data){
   var listname = ctx.ListTitle;
   if (typeof(data) == 'undefined' || data.length == 0) return false;

   var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(ctx.ListTitle);
   for(i in data){

      data[i]['Title']  = data[i]['Name'];
      data[i]['From']   = data[i]['Name'].split('/')[0];
      data[i]['To']     = data[i]['Name'].split('/')[1];

      var date = moment(data[i]['Date']+' '+data[i]['Time'], 'M/D/YYYY hh:mma');
      data[i]['Date'] = date.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');

      delete data[i]['Name'];
      delete data[i]['id'];
      delete data[i]['Time'];

      var item = $.extend({
         "__metadata": { "type": itemType }
      }, data[i]);

      $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items",
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
         data: JSON.stringify(item),
         headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
         },
         success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
         },
         error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

ListTitle: `Cotacao`
Var `itemType`: `SP.Data.CotacaoListItem`

My var `item` on context:

```
Ask: "2.9834"
Bid: "2.9787"
Date: "23/04/2015 20:39"
From: "USD"
Rate: "2.9787"
Title: "USD/BRL"
To: "BRL"
__metadata: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Always I receive the error on console:

> POST https://mydomain/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Cotacao')/items 400 (Bad Request)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

---

I have based [this response](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105380/rest-adding-new-list-item) and [this post](https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/create-retrieve-update-and-delete-sharepoint-list-item-using-rest-api-and-jquery/)...

---

## Edit

I've checked the `responseText`:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "pt-BR",
            "value": "Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.DateTime'. See the inner exception for more details."
        }
    }
}
```

**I don't know the correct date format from Sharepoint**

Comment: If you are trying to "get" list by title, shouldn't your ajax request be `type: "GET"`?

Comment: I'm trying add an item on my list @DylanCristy...

Comment: I see.  Also, if you are trying to add the item before rendering the view, instead of calling that function from the `Header` template, you can register it with `overrideCtx.OnPreRender` and it will execute before it gets to any header code.

Comment: I already registered the function on `OnPreRender`, but I still receive error 400. @DylanCristy

Comment: Hi @DylanCristy, I've edited the question... Can you help me?

Comment: SP may be expecting an ISO formatted date string.  Try `data[i]['Date'] = date.toISOString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved error changing date format...

This:

```
  var date = moment(data[i]['Date']+' '+data[i]['Time'], 'M/D/YYYY hh:mma');
  data[i]['Date'] = date.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
```

To this:

```
  var date = moment(data[i]['Date']+' '+data[i]['Time'], 'M/D/YYYY hh:mma');
  data[i]['Date'] = date.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ');
```

Comment: This format is called ISO8601 and I believe the Time part is optional so you could also just give YYYY-MM-DD to SP.