# Item not creating while using REST in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a requirement where I have to copy list items from one list to another using REST. The requirement is that the data copied from list 'A' should be 90 days older than today. So I have written it on the click function of a button. I am able to fetch the data but while creating the items in list 'B', ajax call is successful but items are not getting created in the list (it does not go into the error function).

Note: to get items I've made REST calls in batches of 5000 and pushed it into one item array, as the limit of REST
calls is 5000. There is no problem in getting items, just creating new items.

The code is given below:

```
var TrainingReqList = "training_requests";
var ArchiveList = "Archived_training_requests";
var TrainingReqArchiveListData = [];
function onClickArchival() {
    var copyItem = {};      //array in which data fetched will be copied and this will be passed into create item function
    var toCopyCount = 0;
    getTRdata();        //funtion to get data in batches of 5000
    for (i = 0; i < TrainingReqArchiveListData.length; i++) {   //when all data is pushed into the array, conditions are invoked
        var archivedate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + (-90)));
        var createddate = new Date(TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]['Created']);
        if (createddate <= archivedate) {
            if (TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]['Status'].toString() != "New Request" && TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]['Status'].toString() != "Pending Agent Confirmation" && TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]['Status'].toString() != "Training Date Confirmed") {
                var created = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]['Created'];
                var modified = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]['Modified'];
                var createduserId = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]['AuthorId'];
                var modifiedUserId = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]['EditorId'];
                toCopyCount++;

            for (var propertyName in TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]) {
                if (TrainingReqArchiveListData[i].hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {   //for copying the properties of list where data is fetched from
                    if (TrainingReqArchiveListData[i][propertyName] != null && TrainingReqArchiveListData[i][propertyName].hasOwnProperty('__deferred'))  //exclude deffered objects 
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (propertyName == 'GUID' || propertyName == 'ID' || propertyName == 'Id') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (propertyName == '__metadata') {
                        var targetItemType = "";
                        copyItem['__metadata'] = { 'type': "SP.Data.Archived_x005f_training_x005f_requestsListItem" };
                    }
                }
            }
            //copying data into new array from the fetched data array
            copyItem["Id"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Id"];
            copyItem["Status"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Status"];
            copyItem["send_x0020_webinar_x0020_link_x0"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["send_x0020_webinar_x0020_link_x0"];
            copyItem["Agency_x0020_Name"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Agency_x0020_Name"];
            copyItem["Agent_x0020_Phone_x0020__x0023_"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Agent_x0020_Phone_x0020__x0023_"];
            copyItem["Agency_x0020_Producer_x0020_Code"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Agency_x0020_Producer_x0020_Code"];
            copyItem["send_x0020_webinar_x0020_link_x00"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["send_x0020_webinar_x0020_link_x00"];
            copyItem["Agency_x0020_State"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Agency_x0020_State"];
            copyItem["SE_x0020_Name_x0020_Free_x0020_F"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["SE_x0020_Name_x0020_Free_x0020_F"];
            copyItem["Will_x0020_SE_x0020_be_x0020_pre"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Will_x0020_SE_x0020_be_x0020_pre"];
            copyItem["Role"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Role"];
            copyItem["Training_x0020_Topic"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Training_x0020_Topic"].results[0].toString();
            copyItem["Years_x0020_of_x0020_CL_x0020_Ex"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Years_x0020_of_x0020_CL_x0020_Ex"];
            copyItem["Years_x0020_of_x0020_Travelers_x"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Years_x0020_of_x0020_Travelers_x"];
            copyItem["Scheduling_x0020_Preference"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Scheduling_x0020_Preference"];
            copyItem["Time_x0020_Zone"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Time_x0020_Zone"];
            copyItem["Requester_x0020_Note"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Requester_x0020_Note"];
            copyItem["Date_x0020_Selection"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Date_x0020_Selection"];
            copyItem["Time_x0020_Selection"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Time_x0020_Selection"];
            copyItem["Date_x002f_Time"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Date_x002f_Time"];
            copyItem["Submitted_x0020_ById"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Submitted_x0020_ById"];
            copyItem["AAE_x0020_AssignedId"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["AAE_x0020_AssignedId"];
            copyItem["Admin_x0020_Notes"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Admin_x0020_Notes"];
            copyItem["Region"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Region"];
            copyItem["Training_x0020_Type"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Training_x0020_Type"];
            copyItem["New_x0020_Appointment"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["New_x0020_Appointment"];
            copyItem["Scheduled_x0020_Training"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Scheduled_x0020_Training"];
            copyItem["Breakout_x0020_Session_x0020_Hel"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Breakout_x0020_Session_x0020_Hel"];
            copyItem["OData__x0023__x0020_B_x002f_O_x0020_Pa"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["OData__x0023__x0020_B_x002f_O_x0020_Pa"];
            copyItem["OData__x0023__x0020_of_x0020_Participa"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["OData__x0023__x0020_of_x0020_Participa"];
            copyItem["OData__x0023__x0020_New_x0020_Users"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["OData__x0023__x0020_New_x0020_Users"];
            copyItem["secondary_x0020_training"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["secondary_x0020_training"];
            copyItem["confirmed_x0020_producer_x0020_c"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["confirmed_x0020_producer_x0020_c"];
            copyItem["Primary_x0020_TrainingTopic"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Primary_x0020_TrainingTopic"];
            copyItem["Additional_x0020_attendees"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Additional_x0020_attendees"];
            copyItem["Record_x0020_Status"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Record_x0020_Status"];
            copyItem["RequestID"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["RequestID"];
            copyItem["Created"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Created"];
            copyItem["Notes"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Notes"];
            copyItem["RequestSource"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["RequestSource"];
            copyItem["IfMulti"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["IfMulti"];
            copyItem["Modified"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Modified"];
            copyItem["AAE_x0020_Assigned"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["AAE_x0020_Assigned"];
            copyItem["Submitted_x0020_By"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Submitted_x0020_By"];
            AddListItem(ArchiveList, copyItem); //function call to create new items in Archive list
        }
    }
}
console.log('Total items in ' + TrainingReqList + ': ' + TrainingReqArchiveListData.length);
console.log('Total number of items to be archived to ' + ArchiveList + ': ' + toCopyCount);
}
```

To get data, I've used the following functions

```
function getTRdata() {
    var checkTopIdFilter = "?$select = Id&$orderby=Id asc&$top=1";
    var callTrainingReqListCheckTopId = GetListItems(TrainingReqList, null, checkTopIdFilter);

    $.when(callTrainingReqListCheckTopId).then(function (tData) {
        if (tData.d.results.length != 0) {
            var startId1 = tData.d.results[0].Id;
            var endId1 = startId1 + 4999;
            var startId2 = endId1 + 1;
            var endId2 = startId2 + 4999;
            var startId3 = endId2 + 1;
            var endId3 = startId3 + 4999;
            var startId4 = endId3 + 1;
            var endId4 = startId4 + 4999;

            var trFilter1 = "?$filter=((Id ge " + startId1 + ") and (Id le " + endId1 + "))&$top=5000";
            var trFilter2 = "?$filter=((Id ge " + startId2 + ") and (Id le " + endId2 + "))&$top=5000";
            var trFilter3 = "?$filter=((Id ge " + startId3 + ") and (Id le " + endId3 + "))&$top=5000";

            var callTrainingReqList1 = GetListItems(TrainingReqList, null, trFilter1);  //rest call to get data of first 5000
            var callTrainingReqList2 = GetListItems(TrainingReqList, null, trFilter2);  //rest call to get data of next 5000
            var callTrainingReqList3 = GetListItems(TrainingReqList, null, trFilter3);  //rest call to get data of next 5000

            $.when(callTrainingReqList1, callTrainingReqList2, callTrainingReqList3).then(function (trData1, trData2, trData3) {
                for (var i = 0; i < trData1[0].d.results.length; i++) {
                    var confDateTime, createdDateTime, modifiedDateTime;
                    if (trData1[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time != null || trData1[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time != undefined) confDateTime = new Date(trData1[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
                    else confDateTime = trData1[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time;
                    if (trData1[0].d.results[i].Created != null || trData1[0].d.results[i].Created != undefined) createdDateTime = new Date(trData1[0].d.results[i].Created).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
                    else createdDateTime = trData1[0].d.results[i].Created;
                    if (trData1[0].d.results[i].Modified != null || trData1[0].d.results[i].Modified != undefined) modifiedDateTime = new Date(trData1[0].d.results[i].Modified).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
                    else modifiedDateTime = trData1[0].d.results[i].Modified;

                    TrainingReqArchiveListData.push(trData1[0].d.results[i]);   //pushing first 5000 data into array
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < trData2[0].d.results.length; i++) {
                    var confDateTime, createdDateTime, modifiedDateTime;
                    if (trData2[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time != null || trData2[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time != undefined) confDateTime = new Date(trData2[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
                    else confDateTime = trData2[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time;
                    if (trData2[0].d.results[i].Created != null || trData2[0].d.results[i].Created != undefined) createdDateTime = new Date(trData2[0].d.results[i].Created).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
                    else createdDateTime = trData2[0].d.results[i].Created;
                    if (trData2[0].d.results[i].Modified != null || trData2[0].d.results[i].Modified != undefined) modifiedDateTime = new Date(trData2[0].d.results[i].Modified).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
                    else modifiedDateTime = trData2[0].d.results[i].Modified;

                    TrainingReqArchiveListData.push(trData2[0].d.results[i]);   //pushing next 5000 data into array
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < trData3[0].d.results.length; i++) {
                    var confDateTime, createdDateTime, modifiedDateTime;
                    if (trData3[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time != null || trData3[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time != undefined) confDateTime = new Date(trData3[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
                    else confDateTime = trData3[0].d.results[i].Date_x002f_Time;
                    if (trData3[0].d.results[i].Created != null || trData3[0].d.results[i].Created != undefined) createdDateTime = new Date(trData3[0].d.results[i].Created).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
                    else createdDateTime = trData3[0].d.results[i].Created;
                    if (trData3[0].d.results[i].Modified != null || trData3[0].d.results[i].Modified != undefined) modifiedDateTime = new Date(trData3[0].d.results[i].Modified).format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
                    else modifiedDateTime = trData3[0].d.results[i].Modified;

                    TrainingReqArchiveListData.push(trData3[0].d.results[i]);   //pushing next 5000 data into array
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

function GetListItems(listName, id, filter) {
    if (id != null) { var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items/getbyid('" + id + "')" + filter; }
    else { var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items" + filter; }
    return $.ajax({
        url: siteURL,
        async: false,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });
}
```

To write data into new list:

```
function AddListItem(listname, ArchiveMetadata) {   //function to create new items in Archive list (ArchiveMetadata is passed as copyItem)
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listname + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(ArchiveMetadata),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Item Id: " + ArchiveMetadata.Id + " copied");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data.statusText + " : " + data.responseText);
            console.log("Item Id: " + ArchiveMetadata.Id + " not copied");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wht i got is you are trying to enter values in ID field which is counter which automatically gets updated by sharepoint in the below line:

Try removing this:
copyItem["Id"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Id"];

Comment: I changed the code from `copyItem["Id"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Id"];` to `itemId = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["Id"];` as I have to print which Id has been copied.
Then  I passed itemId to 'AddListItem' function and in its success I printed
`console.log('Item Id:' + itemId + ' copied.');`
It is printing correct, i.e. it is going in to success function, but when I check the list 'Archived_training_requests' but items are not created.
Can you check?

Comment: I beleive because of this records: copyItem["OData__x0023__x0020_B_x002f_O_x0020_Pa"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["OData__x0023__x0020_B_x002f_O_x0020_Pa"];
            copyItem["OData__x0023__x0020_of_x0020_Participa"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["OData__x0023__x0020_of_x0020_Participa"];
            copyItem["OData__x0023__x0020_New_x0020_Users"] = TrainingReqArchiveListData[i]["OData__x0023__x0020_New_x0020_Users"];

Comment: These columns are present in both lists when I checked on making REST calls on IE. I tried to execute after removing them but no effect
I debugged on chrome initially the debugger goes out of ajax call after running it for all the items but does not go to success or fail.
Then it goes out of the initial click function onClickArchival() printing the total items. Then it goes to the html file, then a file named ScriptResource.axd -> VM11097 ->jquery-1.8.0.min.js ->back to the success function in side the ajax call and starts printing the `console.log('Item Id:' + itemId + ' copied.');`

Comment: Do it in batches of 99. REST handles better till 100. after than you have run looping rest query to get all records.

Comment: Right now I'm just doing it for 12 items. And also tried for inserting just one column, commenting everything else.

Comment: Add contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose", in AddListItem $.ajax request

Comment: if still have the issue console.log(ArchiveMetadata) before making our request and compare with the below:
 {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": newItemTitle
    };

Comment: Take a look at this request http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105380/adding-new-list-item-using-rest

Comment: `function AddListItem(listname, ArchiveMetadata, itemId) {       console.log(ArchiveMetadata);
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listname + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(ArchiveMetadata),
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }`

Comment: In console
'Object {__metadata: Object, Status: "Training Complete", send_x0020_webinar_x0020_link_x0: "Mike Robertson", Agency_x0020_Name: "AGENCY ONE AZ LLC", Agent_x0020_Phone_x0020__x0023_: "480-516-4878"…}'

Comment: On expanding metadata:
'__metadata
:
Object
type
:
"SP.Data.Archived_x005f_training_x005f_requestsListItem"
__proto__
:
Object'

Comment: I guess on of the column is throwind the issue. you have to comment all columns and try working with one columns for effective results. To dentify which column is throwing issue

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it was a silly mistake from my end, the code and data was correct and it was getting copied

Comment: Hi, can you also guide me on how to preserve created, modified, created by and modified by for the same. It should be the same as previous list but it's getting current date time and logged in user.

Comment: You can access values in the field Author.... and create custom columns of single line of text and copy.