# jQuery Ajax Unauthorized error on POST

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, error

Trying to create my first web part for SharePoint online that writes to a list. But when I do a post using jQuery ajax I receive an Unauthorized error. Any help you be greatly appreciated.

I am reusing some found code so maybe I'm missing something:

**I first get the form digest:**

```
var formDigest;       

$.ajax({
          async: false,
          url: "https://#################/_api/contextinfo",
          type: "POST",
          headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "contentType": "text/xml"
          },
          success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            var requestdigest = data;
            formDigest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
          },
          error: function (err) {
            debugger;
            alert(err.statusText);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
          }
        });
```

**Then I try to post to the list:**

```
$.ajax({  
              async: false,                   
              url: "https://#################/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestList')/items",  
              method: "POST", 
              data: JSON.stringify({  
                  '__metadata': {  
                      'type': 'SP.Data.TestListListItem'
                  },  
                  'Title': "TEST"
              }),  
              headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": formDigest,
                "X-HTTP-Method": "POST",
                "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED": "f"
              },  
              success: function(data) {      
                  alert("Item created successfully");
              },  
              error: function(error) {      
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));              
              }  
        
          });
```

When I try to do the insert I get a Unauthorized error.

Now I am able to do a get to the list but when I do a POST the error occurs.

Comment: Do you have at least contribute/edit permissions on SharePoint list? Are you able to create/update list items from UI/browser? Also, are you trying to create a new item or update existing list item?

Comment: Did you try without the `X-HTTP-Method` and `X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED` headers?  I've never used those headers when doing a `POST` to create an item.  I do use `X-HTTP-Method` when doing a `POST` to _update_ an existing item, but it doesn't look like that's what you are doing there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a new list item in SharePoint list, use below code:

```
function CreateListItem() {
    $.ajax
        ({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestList')/items",
            type: "POST",
            headers:
            {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            data: JSON.stringify
            ({
                __metadata:
                {
                    type: "SP.Data.TestListListItem"
                },
                Title: "TEST"
            }),
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("Failed");
            }
        });
}
```

**Source**: [Create List Item in SharePoint using REST API](https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/create-list-item-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api)

You can find more similar examples at: [Adding new list item using REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105380/adding-new-list-item-using-rest)

**Microsoft official Docs**: [Working with list items by using REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-list-items-by-using-rest)

---

More information about permissions on SharePoint lists: [Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782)

Comment: There does not seem to be any difference between this code and my code above. They both produce the same 401 error.

Comment: Is there a setting in Sharepoint that I need to change to enable Post messages ?

Comment: You need to grant yourself at contribute/edit permissions on SharePoint list. check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782).

Comment: I am the owner of the list. I am able to make a post using spHttpClient.